# Float error with PNAS template

Tags: floats, compiling, overleaf

I'm attempting to use the PNAS template at writelatex.com however I'm encountering a strange compiling error when the default title is changed to one that is long enough to require a second line, and if any of the characters on that second line have tails (i.e. elements which go beneath the line).

The error "Float(s) Lost" is shown in this screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvaz1bhu9h6ys0c/Screenshot%202014-04-20%2015.47.26.png

The template is available here:
https://www.writelatex.com/979364xxsmgy

Note the error occurs on my own local latex install as well as on writelatex.com. Can anyone advise on the cause of the problem?

Comment: Tables and figures must go after `\end{article}`; if you put them before that line, they disappear.

Comment: @egreg, it looks like all of the tables and figures are below the \end{article} line. Unless there is one I'm overlooking.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a problem with the old version of `pnastwo.cls` from 2008. There's a new version from 2013 available here:
http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/LaTex.xhtml

If you upload the latest version of `pnastwo.cls`, that seems to do the job.